# Browser alert popup is not showing on current window in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The alert popup is not showing on the current window it shows on other browsers (same alert popup).
This bug is appearing only on IE, working fine with chrome and Mozilla

```
 if (iNum > 99) {
            document.getElementById(id).value = '';
            alert('value not be greater than'); //this alert popup open in another broswer in IE
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What is the version of IE that you're using ?

Comment: IE version 11.0 @SachinthaNayanajith

Comment: Did you try adding the compatibility view - @SiddharthVyas ?

Comment: @SachinthaNayanajith sorry I didn't understand can you please explore more about

Comment: I added an answer. You can try that. @SiddharthVyas

Comment: @SachinthaNayanajith for me not working you added an answer below

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure your console doesn't show any errors and correct them if there are any.
2. Be sure you didn't disable browser prompts on IE
3. Try using `window.alert()`, it's possible (though improbable) that another `alert()` is conflicting with window's.
4. If you have console support, try `console.log(alert);` and see what it says. It should be something like:

   ```
   function alert() {
       [native code]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

*You can try turning on the compatibility view by Settings -> compatibility view Settings and adding your website url there.

*Or you can turn on the compatibility view by putting this meta tag in the head tag of your page as shown below

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<head>
```

you can refer [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/hh920756(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)  to learn about compatibility modes.